# iphone how to use UITextField pass value to cell.detailTextLabel

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, tableview

My problem is i need get user input the value then pass to detailTextlabel,but where i pass to detailtextlabel is null.

My code here.

```
    - (IBAction) scheduleAlarm:(id) sender {
    [eventText resignFirstResponder];
    [numText resignFirstResponder];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    // Get the current date
    NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

    // Break the date up into components
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit ) 
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) 
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];

    // Set up the fire time
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
    [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
    [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
    [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
    // Notification will fire in one minute
    [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
    //[dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
    [dateComps release];

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
   // localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    //string =  [numText.text retain];
     string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:numText.text];
    numText = [self numText];
    [self.view insertSubview:numText atIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"%@",string);
    // Notification details
    localNotif.alertBody = [eventText text];

    // Set the action button
    localNotif.alertAction = @"Send SMS";

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    // Specify custom data for the notification
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];
    //[numText release];
    [self.tableview reloadData];

}
```

at 1st i pass the button i can get the value.but where i go to table view see is out (null) to me.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
   // if (cell == nil) {
    //  cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    //} 
    // Configure the cell...

    notificationArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    UILocalNotification *notif = [notificationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   //  NSString *enNote = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:string];


    [cell.textLabel setText:notif.alertBody];

    NSString *abc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@",[notif.fireDate description], string];
    NSLog(@"%@",string);
    [cell.detailTextLabel  setText:abc];
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

    //cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;




    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of  **cell.detailTextLabel** use **cell.textLabel.text**

like:

> NSString *abc = [NSString
>   stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n
>   %@",[notif.fireDate description],
>   string];
>       NSLog(@"%@",string);
>
> cell.textLabel.text = abc;

Comment: tat one i have function to do.i need to use cell.detailTextLabel to show the string.

Comment: Is detailTextLabel is a UILabel. If it is UILabel u can try this way
[detailTextLabel setText:@"abc"];
cell.contentView = detailTextLabel or [cell.contentView addSubView:detailTextLabel];

Comment: no.tat detailtextlabel is in tableview cell tat one.now my problem is i cnt get the string value by UITextField.

Comment: sry i got where u going worng. Now u try it will work
if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

Comment: hmmm,no this.now my question is i have IBOutlet UITextField *numText; use interfacer builder.where i fill the numText i got value;then i need pass to table view use cell.detailTextLabel to show back the numText when i fill in.

Comment: sry for my bad english.make u no understand my question.

Comment: 1stly i don't know where u r going wrong. Now i tried myself it's working for me.Ok try with simple way before setting any string to detailTextlabel try this way 
if (cell == nil) { cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; }
cell.textLabel.text = @"asdjgdgs";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"abc";
Even now if it doesn't work there may be other problem in your coding. ;)

Comment: can u tell me what nsstring abc is printing in console.

Comment: tat one i want printing date and phone number.so [notif.fireDate description] is printing date.is ok work~!.but the problem is string no working.string = phone number by user fill in.